# how to extract value from a column which in json format using pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe, where there is one column(quite long strings) in json string, which has many keys, where I am only interested in one key.  May I know how to extract the value for that key?

here is the example of the string of the column userbehavior:

```
[{"num":"1234","Projections":"test", "intent":"test", "Mtime":11333.....}]
```

I wish to extract the value for "Mtime" only, i tried using:

```
user_hist_df=user_hist_df.select(get_json_object(user_hist_df.userbehavior, '$.Mtime').alias("Time"))
```

However it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right, it isn't working because your JSON is an array of objects. Just change to this:

```py
get_json_object('userbehavior', '$[*].Mtime').alias("Time")
```

Comment: it works now, however, I explode my array of objects, now it is a string like '{"num":"1234","Projections":"test", "intent":"test", "Mtime":11333.....}' , it does not work :(

Comment: When it's an array of objects you must use `$[*].Mtime`. if it's an object instead, your solution should work. Create another question describing what you did and what's happening in details

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract from a json column you can use - `from_json()`  and specify the **schema**
e.g. **`df = df.withColumn("parsed_col", from_json($"Body",MapType(StringType,StringType)))`**

Once you parse the json as per the schema - just extract the column as per your need

**`df = df.withColumn("col_1", col("parsed_col").getItem("col_1"))`**

Comment: it gives error keyType should be datatype